# CCI Y-axiz label

Tags: label, indicator, yaxis, cci

Need some help adding a fixed static label in the right side y-axiz for the CCI indicator I use.

The levels where the label must display are fixed ; -200, -100, 0, 100, 200.

This is the 5 horizontal lines that I use.

Would appreciate help adding the labels to the CCI indicator

```
//Level Lines
hline(0, title="Zero Line", color=#9c27b0, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(100, title="Hundred Line", color=#9c27b0, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(-100, title="Minus Hundred Line", color=#9c27b0, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(200, title="Two Hundred Line", color=#9c27b0, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(-200, title="Minus Two Hundred Line", color=#9c27b0, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
```

Tried using label.set_text() and variations of this